# using variables in if/else statetement

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I am using props to get an input value with useRef, which value should limit the number of reminders to save by the user. using if statement, I want that the user can save reminders more than the input value obtain with the props in the code below

```
const maxW = useRef()
const Wmax = maxW.current.value
console.log(Wmax) // value = 8

if (Reminders.length !== Wmax) {
  Reminders.push(Reminder);
  console.log(Reminders);
} else {
  console.log("can not save any more Reminders");
}
```

when I console log "Wmax" the right value is display in the console
as the image below
[value of Wmax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p0k5.png)

but unfortunately, the if statement does not read the Wmax value and hence the user can still save more reminders even after reaching the value of Wmax, as shown below
[exceed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh1h0.png)

```
TextReminder.js?1337:59 [{…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8

TextReminder.js?1337:59 (2) [{…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}

]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 

{…}, {…}]

TextReminder.js?1337:43 8
TextReminder.js?1337:59 (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: Wondering if Wmax is a string, try `if(Reminders.length !== parseInt(Wmax)){//...}`

Comment: @WasimAbuzaher, thank you so much. Wmax, is a string. this help me